# HTML Emails - Outlook 2007/2010 border collapse/spacing issue

Tags: html, email, html-email, outlook-2010, outlook-2007

So, I'm having issues with Outlook 2007/2010 spacing (border collapse?) issue.

Here is an image as to what it is doing (the Hurry Now.. text gets pushed down) 
[image]

Here is what it is supposed to look like & works fine in all other email clients.
[image]

Here is my snippet of code for the Hero section

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="561" align="center" bgcolor="#4b88cf" style="font-family: Tahoma, Arial, Verdana, sans-serif; font-size:40px; font-weight:normal; line-height:40px; text-align:left; color:#ffffff; border-collapse:collapse; mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt;">
    <tr>
        <td width="561" height="37" style="font-size: 0; line-height: 0" bgcolor="#4b88cf"> &nbsp;</td>
    </tr> <!-- end spacer --> 
    <tr> 
        <td height="48" valign="top" style="color: #ffffff;"><font color="#ffffff">Save 10% on all</font></td> 
    </tr> <!-- heading -->
    <tr> 
        <td height="48" valign="top" style="color: #ffffff;"><font color="#ffffff">EasyACCT 2013 products.</font></td> 
    </tr> <!-- heading -->
    <tr> 
        <td height="48" valign="top" style="color: #ffffff;"><font color="#ffffff">Only 4 days left!</font></td> 
    </tr> <!-- heading -->
    <tr>
        <td width="561" height="25" style="font-size: 0; line-height: 0" bgcolor="#4b88cf"> &nbsp;</td>
    </tr> <!-- spacer here -->
    <!-- start button --> 
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="left" style="font-family: Tahoma, Arial, Verdana, sans-serif; font-size:14px; font-weight:normal; line-height:20px; text-align:left; color:#ffffff; border-collapse:collapse; mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt;">
                <tr>
                    <td style="border-collapse: collapse;"><img src="http://intuit.pistonclients.com/13-intu-r-1629/images/left-btn.png" border="0" style="display: block;" alt="left side button"/></td> <!-- left side button -->
                    <td align="center" style="font-weight: bold; border-collapse: collapse;" bgcolor="#f0640f"><a href="http://accountants.intuit.com/accounting/lp/quickbooks/easyacct-renew.jsp?s_cid=EM" style="text-decoration: none;"><font color="#ffffff" style="text-decoration: none;">Renew Now to Save 10%</font></a></td> 
                    <td style="border-collapse: collapse;"><img src="http://intuit.pistonclients.com/13-intu-r-1629/images/right-btn.png" border="0" style="display: block;" alt="right side button"/></td> <!-- right side button -->
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <!-- end button -->
    <tr>
        <td width="561" height="15" style="font-size: 0; line-height: 0; border-collapse: collapse;" bgcolor="#4b88cf">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr> <!-- spacer here -->
    <tr>
        <td valign="top" width="561" style="font-size: 18px; color: #ffffff; border-collapse: collapse;"><font color="#ffffff">Hurry, offer ends October 31!</font><sup style="font-size: 12px; line-height: 0; vertical-align: 8px"><font color="#ffffff">1</font></sup></td>
    </tr> 
    <tr>
        <td width="561" height="23" style="font-size: 0; line-height: 0; border-collapse: collapse;" bgcolor="#4b88cf">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr> <!-- spacer here -->
</table>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Inconsistent spaces below TD elements in tables in HTML email in Outlook (2007 and 2010)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6520731/inconsistent-spaces-below-td-elements-in-tables-in-html-email-in-outlook-2007-a)

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem I've come across with Outlook 2007,2010 and of course 2013. They don't like small cells.

I've found this code has worked for me and gone through Litmus tests.

```
<tr height="1">
   <td width="482" height="1" align="left" valign="top" background="#000000" style="background:#000000;font-size: 1px; line-height: 0px; mso-line-height-rule: exactly;">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
```

The mso-line-height-rule: exactly; is an outlook specific style. The font-size: 1px should match however much height you want your cell to be. The line-height: 0px; zero's out any line-height space.

HOWEVER, after testing your code snippet with the updated cells this doesn't seem to be the actual problem. I made the spacer cells black so I could better see what was actually going on.

[image: code with spacer cells made black]

The black spacer cell ends well above the copy, ie. it's not pushing your text down. The issue is actually the cell with the white copy in it.

I added a line height to the cell and removed the border-collapse:collapse; (you don't need it on individual cells. You may just want to double check your superscripts are all good.

```
    <tr>
    <td valign="top" width="561" style="font-size: 18px; line-height: 20px; color: #ffffff;"><font color="#ffffff">Hurry, offer ends October 31!<sup style="font-size: 12px; line-height: 0; vertical-align: 8px"><font color="#ffffff">1</font></sup></font></td>
</tr>
```

This was the result:

[image]

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Outlook has a minimum cell height of 19px, so the 15px cell you have as the spacer in seems to be expanding, evern though you have the font-size and line-height zero'd out.

An alternative way to do it, is instead of having your text sandwiched between two spacer rows, make 1 taller row and vertically center it instead:

```
<tr>
    <td valign="middle" width="561" height="50" style="font-size: 18px; color: #ffffff; border-collapse: collapse;"><font color="#ffffff">Hurry, offer ends October 31!</font><sup style="font-size: 12px; line-height: 0; vertical-align: 8px"><font color="#ffffff">1</font></sup></td>
</tr>
```

Throughout your whole email, you don't really need separate rows for each line of text, just use `<br>` instead to separate the rows.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with John. Just use the breaks to create vertical whitespace. You're making it more difficult for yourself, without any reason :-)
Just put the right attributes at their right place: your use of the font-tag is overwhelming, as is the `border-collapse:collapse` and the `font-size:0; line-height:0;`.

If you want to create a whitespace, give a height at the TD (20px) and `style="font-size:20px; line-height:20px;"`, with a BR-tag inside (no nbsp).

See my example:

```
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="561" align="center" style="border-collapse:collapse; mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt;">
        <tr><td bgcolor="#4b88cf" align="left" style="font-family:Tahoma, Arial, Verdana, sans-serif; font-size:40px; line-height:46px; color:#ffffff;"><br />Save 10% on all<br />EasyACCT 2013 products.<br />Only 4 days left!<br /><br /></td></tr>
        <tr><td bgcolor="#4b88cf"><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="left"><tr>
            <td width="12" height="50" bgcolor="#f0640f"><img src="http://intuit.pistonclients.com/13-intu-r-1629/images/left-btn.png" width="12" height="50" alt="" border="0" style="display:block;" /></td>
            <td bgcolor="#f0640f" align="center" style="font-family:Tahoma, Arial, Verdana, sans-serif; font-size:14px; line-height:20px; color:#ffffff;"><a href="http://accountants.intuit.com/accounting/lp/quickbooks/easyacct-renew.jsp?s_cid=EM" style="color:#ffffff; text-decoration:none;"><strong style="color:#ffffff;">Renew Now to Save 10%</strong></a></td>
            <td width="14" bgcolor="#f0640f"><img src="http://intuit.pistonclients.com/13-intu-r-1629/images/right-btn.png" width="14" height="50" alt="" border="0" style="display:block;" /></td>
        </tr></table></td></tr>
        <tr><td bgcolor="#4b88cf" style="font-family:Tahoma, Arial, Verdana, sans-serif; font-size:18px; line-height:20px; color:#ffffff;"><br />Hurry, offer ends October 31!<sup style="font-size:12px; line-height:0; vertical-align:8px">1</sup><br /><br /></td></tr></table>
```